# Is there a way to automatically update the data in the page if a data is updated in cloud firestore using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make an app that will automatically update the displayed data if the data inside the cloud firestore has been updated by the admin or other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing are known are [realtime listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) in Firestore. You can attach one by calling `onSnapshot` on a reference to the data or query, and will then be called with the current data right away and subsequently whenever the data gets updated.

To show this data in the UI of your Flutter app, you can use a `StreamBuilder` as shown in this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) in the documentation.